# What is the most descriptive way to define HTTP basic authentication header in a WADL?

Tags: http, rest, wadl

I would like to describe HTTP basic authentication within a WADL, what is the most descriptive way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since basic authentication is implemented as a header, simply use a param within your request.

```
<method name="GET">
    <request>
        <param name="Authorization" style="header" type="xs:string" required="true" />
        <!-- other headers... -->
    </request>

    <response>
        <!-- repsonse.. -->
    </response>
</method>
```